# How to show that an non-linear ODE has at least two solutions in $C^2(0,1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm given a differential equation that goes as following

$$-\frac{d}{dx}(u(x)u'(x))=1$$

with the auxiliary condition of $u(0)=u(1)=0$ and the set $C^2(0,1)=\left\{g\in C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1] \mid g(0)=g(1)=0\right\}$

**What I tried:**

I used that $uu'=\frac{(u')^2}{2}$ Integrating both sides, I get

$$u'(x)^2=-2x+C_1\implies u'(x)= \pm \sqrt{-2(x+C_1)}$$

does it hold that since there is a $\pm$, the solution will have at least or only two solutions?

Comment: Hint: $u u^\prime \ne (u^\prime)^2/2$, but $u u^\prime = (u^2)^\prime /2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, except for some little typos. In this case, after integrating twice you find that $$
u(x)^2=-x^2+C_1x+C_2.
$$
Using the first initial condition $u(0)=0$ you get then $C_2=0$. Similarly, using that $u(1)=0$ one can infer that $C_1=1$. Then, the solution satisfies $$
u(x)^2=(-x^2+x)=x(1-x).
$$
Observe that for $x\in(0,1)$ we have $x(1-x)>0$, and hence, on $(0,1)$ there are at least two solution $$
u_1(x)=\sqrt{x(1-x)} \qquad \hbox{ and } \qquad u_2(x)=-\sqrt{x(1-x)}.
$$